# Angular + Nodejs API - Best practice to handle request response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm writing my first API in node.js and front end in Angular.

Wanted to ask what is the best practice for handling responses. So by this i mean should my API always return codes e.g. `403` or is a `success` = `true`/`false` fine?

Is there any security consideration between the two, i.e. is one more secure?

So in essence which of the 2 below should i use?

```
if (res.data.success){
   //to do something
}
```

vs

```
if (res.status == 403) {
   //to do something
}
```

Or am i worrying about nothing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> The Good Practice is :-
>   Below code itself handle errors It self dont Use if and Else .. use the Following type angular Update Best Praactice

```
 $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/someUrl'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available
      }, function errorCallback(response) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
      });
```

Error responses automatically handled by pre-suported block errorcallback

Comment: Ah ok - i see that makes sense.
Is there anythiing wrong if I chose instead to do it in an if statement my way? Wrong in terms of security vulnerability?

Comment: you know i tried to do like if and else .. the Problem is error is not being catched by if else block  idk actual reason for it.. but http error handling is way better than if else for sure ..

Comment: Cool - well the Angular documentation suggests this so lets stick to that :-)
Thanks for your help mate

Comment: Ah - i just tried this and for a status code of 403 its going into the successCallback. Have you seen this before?

Comment: How are you using it  ? can you update the code ? :Let me know what angular version are  you using .. you need to use latest Version .  Older version has different approach

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104635/discussion-between-n-v-prasad-and-usermod2).